# Obtaining sensitive data from the user and storing it without hashing so that it can be restored

Tags: c#, security, encryption, .net-core

I'd like to ask for some advice on the app security when it comes to getting the password from the user and storing it.

I'm developing a tool using .NET Core (console project) and Selenium WebDriver to automate a process on a website, which requires authentication, and my concerns are following:

**1. Getting the password from the user (using console) and securely handle it**

**2. Storing the password in a secure manner**

Regarding the first point:

- I've found an [answer on
  SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43711511/8297552) pointing out that
  using
  [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netcore-2.1)
  doesn't fully prevent sensitive data to be read as at some point it
  has to be converted to/from normal string. I have come across [the
  solution](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0600__Security/Readpasswordfromconsole.htm)

  for getting user input from console using `SecureString`s, but
  according to what's written
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26191090/8297552)
  `SecureStringToBSTR` has to be used to handle the sensitive data in a
  secure way. However, `SecureStringToBSTR` [is not included in .NET
  Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44542611/8297552), because it's
  available only for Windows thus I'm stuck.

As for the second point:

- I cannot hash the password as it has to be restored. At first I
  wanted to use platform specific solutions and check the current
  platform in the app, but after a research I found out that there's API only for [DPAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for Windows, there's no API for KeyChain in MacOS ([there's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50976213/8297552) some workaround) and Linux doesn't have a unified way of storing sensitive data at all. The only solution I can think of is to force the user to generate public/private keys (using for example RSA [which is available on all platforms](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/cross-platform-cryptography.md), encrypt the password using public key and require private key to retrieve the password. Then I would store the encrypted password either in `appsettings.json` or as an Environmental variable as desribed [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/store-protect-sensitive-data-dotnet-core). Unfortunately Azure Key Vault is [not free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/key-vault/)

I am aware that there are many questions similar to this, but:

- I couldn't find any regarding storing passwords, most sources focus on hashing them, however, it doesn't apply to described use case
- Virtually all are focused on ASP.NET Core MVC

Thanks in advance for the hints.

Comment: Are you certain that the service you are interacting with on behalf of your users does not provide some sort of OAuth interface?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Unfortunately no, there's no OAuth, no API.  I've just checked just  to be 100% sure. I need to use a browser to automate the process.

Comment: Uhhhh.  Are you sure?  Why do you need to use a browser vs just make the requests the browser makes yourself?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Maybe I'm missing something, but I know two ways of filling the userName and password fields on that website: detect the proper textfields, simulate user input and perform click action on a relevant button. The second one (which I've just found) is that the fields can be filled in by calling appropriate JS function in a browser console. After seeing your question I assume it might be possible to perform the logging in manually and check what requests the browser has fired, am I right?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it seems like you want to log one of your users into their account with a 3rd party provider, correct?  If this is the case, I don't understand at all why you want to involve the browser?  Simply make the same HTTP request from your own code?  Does that make sense or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark No, there's no third party provider. After checking out the requests made by a browser it turns out that some random data is added to a header, even for the same combination of username and password the generated data is always different, so I guess I have to use the primitive method of authentication using a browser.

Comment: That really isn't the way to solve the problem.